# Ajax simple login

Tags: ajax, function, return

I have this simple Ajax code, my question is only, what does data.logged return, and what i need to have in the logged.php file...

I'm new to ajax, sorry for the dumb question...

```
$.ajax('logged.php', {
                                data: {
                                    login:  login,
                                    pass:   pass
                                },
                                success: function(data)
                                {
                                    if (data.logged)
                                    {
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                            document.location.href = 'index.php'
                                        }, 2000);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                        formLogin.clearMessages();
                                        displayError('Utilizador ou password errados');
                                        }, 2000);
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function()
                                {
                                    formLogin.clearMessages();
                                    displayError('Error while contacting server, please try again');
                                }
                         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side, adding `dataType : 'json'` worked for me.

```
$.ajax('handler.php', {
  data: {
    login:  login,
    pass:   pass
  },
  dataType : 'json',
  success: function(data)
  {
    //code here
  }

  //more code here
}
```

And then on the server side:

```
$user = $_GET['login'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$result = array();
if( /* login logic here */) {
    $result['logged'] = 'true';
} else {
    $result['logged'] = false;
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) AJAX request which will be expecting responseText in [JSON](http://jquery.com/) format. In this case, it seems like the JSON returned by your PHP file only needs to have a single property `logged` which will be either `true` or `false` depending on whether or not the login was successful.

Comment: so in the php only needed to have someething like this? return json_encode("true");

Comment: @nunong21 I'm not a PHP developer, so I really couldn't say. That doesn't look like it would know to call the property `logged` though.

Comment: So what do you suggest to do a simple login? :)

Comment: @nunong21 The jQuery AJAX call is fine. I can't help you with the server-side part because I don't know PHP or anything about what it is you're trying to build, but the client-side part (the jQuery in your question) is perfectly suitable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help man :) But what does the ajax needs to look like to be true?

Comment: The JSON response should look like this: `{"logged" : true}`.